# How to add shortlist feature to ionic app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ionic-framework

I have a list of items and I want to add **Shortlist item feature** like shopping apps have "add to cart" function.
Can Anybody tell me how to add a button for shortlisting items from a list in ionic?

Comment: what have you achived so for send me the example pnkr

Comment: @Mohan I am sending you a demo but on jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Atula/pofakdpf/). I am receving a list in the output. so can you tell me how to shortlist my items.

Comment: send me the response you get

Comment: I can't show you the response but you can assume it as a list of person.